# How to change the value of somthing through input in python

Tags: python

What im trying to do, is when you input "Y" it changes the value of key from 0 - 1. Im fairly new to python, i have tried using the SET function but it hasent worked. Heres my code:

```
 key = 0

 if key==0:
     print("Would you like to pick up the key")
     choice = input("")
     if choice=="Y":
         set(key=1)
```

Comment: Just overwrite the variable, remove set and leave only `key=1`

Comment: Did you notice the TypeError exception when you ran this? What do you think *set()* does?

Comment: ```set``` creates a data structure call a set, which is an unordered collection of objects. It doesn't set the value of key to 1. You just need an ```=``` to give something a value

Comment: Welcome, you can set the key variable directly `key=1`instead of `set(key=1)`, to get your python journey as good as possible start out with a good book, like https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/1593279280

Answer (score 1):

You want to assign 1 to the variable *key* if the input is 'Y' otherwise you want it to be 0

Therefore:

```
key = 1 if input('Would you like to pick up the key') == 'Y' else 0
```

Answer (score 1):

just assign value to it

```
key = 1
```

btw in python you can do this

```
input("Would you like to pick up the key")
```

I think you should go through the basics first. Just take a few minutes in a random tutorial like this

https://www.w3schools.com/python/

Comment: _Random_ tutorials are rarely a good idea. There are way more garbage tutorials than good ones. [The official tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) is a much better recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you wanted to do this here.

```
key = 0

if key==0:
    print("Would you like to pick up the key")
    choice = input("")
    if choice=="Y":
        key = 1

print(key)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
key = 0
print(f"Default value of key: {key}") # f-string is used
inp = input('Would you like to pick up the key: ')
if inp == 'Y' or inp == "y":
    key = 1
    print(f"current value of key: {key}") 
else:
    print(f"current value of key: {key}")
```

Try this code, just change the value of 'key' using input from the user